# std::ofstream as class member deletes the copy constructor?

Tags: c++

the following code only compiles when I remove the definition of the destructor of class Test or when I remove the std::ofstream member. Otherwise I get an error telling me that the copy constructor of Test has been deleted.

Can someone explain why that is? Thank you!

```
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

class Test {
public:
    Test() {};
    ~Test() {};
    std::ofstream ofs;

};

int main() {
    std::vector<Test> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(Test());
}
```

Error message:

```
Error   C2280   'Test::Test(const Test &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

EDIT: If it is only about the deletion of Test's copy constructor because of std::ofstream not being copyable, why does this compile?:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

class Test {
public:
    Test() {};
    //~Test() {};
    std::ofstream ofs;

};

int main() {
    std::vector<Test> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(Test());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If it is only about the deletion of Test's copy constructor because of std::ofstream not being copyable, why does this compile?

The reason that the "empty" destructor stops you is that declaring a destructor suppresses the implicit generation of a move constructor, so `std::vector<Test>::emplace_back` has to *copy* `Test` elements in the case where the vector has to grow.

If you don't have the destructor, then you get the implicit move constructor which uses `std::ofstream::ofstream(ofstream &&)`.

Answer (score 0):

std::ofstream has a deleted copy constructor: [std::ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/). When you put it in the vector `Test` is tried to be copied. This fails because there is no copy constructor for std::ofstream. You need to define your own copy constructor which handles `ofs`:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>

class Test 
{
public:
    Test() {};
    ~Test() {};
    Test(const Test& other) 
    {
    // does not make sense of course
    };
    std::ofstream ofs;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Test> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(Test());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If class has no copy constructor, compiler will generate one for you, which is `default copy constructor`.  `default copy constructor`'s behavior is to copy properties member by member, which may invoke member's copy constructor.

`std::ofstream` is NOT designed for copying, so it marks its copy constructor as deleted to prevent accidentally copying. Then when the `default copy  constructor` invokes the `std::ofstream`'s `deleted` copy constructor, the compile error shows.

Possible solutions:

1. Define your own copy constructor. To control your own copy behavior.
2. Or mark your copy constructor as deleted to prevent your class being copied, same as `std::ofstream`.
3. Or hold your member `ofs` as reference type `std::ofstream&` to capture reference instead of independent instance. (or `std::ofstream*` pointer)

Comment: Thank you. I understand it so far. I have edited my original question. The role of the destructor being explicitly defined or not confuses me.

Comment: Nitpick: The implicitly defined copy-constructor of `Test` is defined as deleted, so option 2 is irrelevant. It is not a "default constructor", that is `Test()`

Comment: @Caleth Thanks. I wrongly write `default copy constructor` as `default constructor`.